# Export to Excel Out of Memory Exception

Tags: sql, vb.net, out-of-memory, export-to-excel

I have an application written in vb.net where users can export files. For this specific file I have the following code-

```
  Private Sub lnkExcelTier2Tier1LinkGet_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal    e  As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkExcelTier2Tier1LinkGet.Click

    Dim dt As Data.DataTable
    Dim reportName As String = Me.lblReportTitleTier1Tier2.Text.Trim()

    Try
        'Grabbing my stored procuder that will be used to get the data
        Dim D As OOBusinessLayer.Common.Dynamic = New OOBusinessLayer.Common.Dynamic("GeneralReporting", "Tier2Tier1LinkGet")

        'Populate table with data
        dt = D.Get()

        'Export data table to excel
        ExportReportVIASuperGrid(dt, reportName, "XLSX")
```

On the export function I keep on getting a System.OutOfMemoryException error. When doing a step though populating the data happens very quickly but then it gets hung on the export.

On the database side I have a view and then the stored procudre just does a select * from the view. It pulls 180,000 rows (12 columns) and takes 3 seconds when querying from SSMS.

If I edit the query to only pull 100 rows it runs smoothly so it seems that the issue is the large amount of data being pulled. But the users need the full data set.

At times the export button has worked and I was able to retrieve the file but the majority of the time I recieve a System.OutOfMemoryException error(all with same amount of data.)

Is there anything I can do in order to bypass this out of memory exception and still provide the full set of data? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using SuperGrid from DevComponents when exporting to Excel?

Comment: Do you want to have dt populated and bypass the export?

Comment: I am using the exporter. I am never actually populating the a grid.